# Gui shutdown: message in the terminal

Tags: client

I closed down bitcoin from the official gui client with *File > Exit* and the following message appeared in bash:

```
************************
UNKNOWN EXCEPTION       
bitcoin in CMyApp::OnUnhandledException()
```

I've seen this before, and on restarting bitcoin, I encounter no problems, and transactions work just fine. Does anybody know what is causing this error message to show?

I'm running debian squeeze just FYI.

Comment: I see several reports of this bug but no solution or analysis. Unfortunately, the error message contains almost no useful information.

Comment: This is a bug report and as such very localized in time. Not suitable for this site IMO.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's its filing on github](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/473).  Seems to be an unresolved issue with the client.